# in spring data mongo how generate Update set object from @Document object in general way - or how upsert(@Document)?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project writing and updating Mongo Documents using Spring Data Mongo. What i need is an upsert semantic that take the document object and decides in data base (of course by just matchin the id) if insert or update is needed.

- I do not want query and load the document before.
- I want to use the @Document object to specify the update (all fields set should be overwritten, fields set to null should not be included in update (seems to be default behavior of driver))

My problem is there seems currently no way?! Either i use "save" from `MongoRepository` what always is an insert. Or i use update or findAndModify that only accepts UpdateDefinition as input.

My idea is now to create generic method that generates an update object from a given object (@Document) and then using update / findAndModify.
But in fact that would just implement an upsert semantic and i ask my self - is this not already implemented?

@Document object -> bson Document / update object -> update with upsert=true

Comment: You can try `MongoTemplate` API's _update_ methods and the "upsert" is generally specified as an "update option". You don't need to query _and_ then perform an update operation (but, its an option) with an of the [MongoDB update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/) operations.

Comment: but these update operations can't be fed with an entity object. I need to make an update object first.